# Jquery bootstrapx clickover strange issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have setup a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/Wbnj2/15/

Follow steps below to get the idea of my problem.

1. Click on + icon on "Add Fruits" *don't do anything yet*
2. Click on + icon on "Add Cars"

Now add some text in input box and click OK.
**OK button stops working but why ????.**

This is really annoying me.
However it works if Click on + icon on "Add Fruits" and leave input box empty ..do nothing but press close button.

So if I keep pressing close button each time this works.If I skip close button and click on next + button, Ok stops working until I reopen clickover and press close button.
Any IDEAS ?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Add Fruits</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
        <select id="fruits">
           <option>apple</option>
           <option>ornage</option>
        </select>
        <button data-attach="fruits " data-key="1 " rel="PERA"  class="btn " type="button"><i class="icon-plus "></i></button>                           
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Add cars</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
        <select id="cars">
           <option>suzuki</option>
           <option>toyota</option>
        </select>
        <button data-attach="cars " data-key="2 " rel="PERA"  class="btn " type="button"><i class="icon-plus "></i></button>                             
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('[rel*=PERA]').clickover(
  {
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'click',
    width: 350,
    title: '<strong>Add new</strong>',
    content: '',
    allow_multiple: false,
    global_close: false,
    onShown: function ()
    {
      var myid = generateUUID();
      var content = '<div id="' + myid + '"><div class="row" style="margin: 10px; "><input class="small m-wrap new_value" type="text" placeholder="Enter Value "/><button class="btn blue update_sel" type="submit"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></button><button class="btn editable-cancel" type="button" data-dismiss="clickover"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div><div class="rspmsg" style="clear: both"> </div></div>';
      $("div.clickover").find("div.popover-content").html(content);

      var me = $('#' + myid);
      var clickover = this;
      var base = $('#' + clickover.options.attach);
      var updatebutton = me.find("button.update_sel");
      var newvalue = me.find("input.new_value");
      var closeclickover = me.find("button.editable-cancel");
      updatebutton.click(function (event)
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
          // heavy lifting
          base.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 13).attr("selected", "selected").text(newvalue.val()));
          closeclickover.click();
        }, 100);
      });

    },
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If I add clickover option  `onHidden: function () {alert("hiding");},`
then it starts working.But If I take out alert from onhidden, it stops working again.

Comment: Following the sequence you said, the second tooltip it's not inline with the input but if you start by clicking the second plus button it appears inline (aligned). Maybe it has something to do with your problem.

Comment: Forget it, seems a javascript/jquery problem but the alignment difference does exist.